# What grade of sodium fluoride is needed for preservation of urine for drug and alcohol testing?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

We are preparing DUI test kits and the distributor we purchased our sodium fluoride vials from is no longer in service.  We are having difficulty finding a new supplier.  Would food grade work for this application?  Food grade can be purchased online and we can fill the vials ourselves eliminating the issue.  Only .2ml is needed for the application.  For the process, the officer opens the lid on the plastic vials and drops the sodium fluoride into the urine specimen, then seals it back up and ships it off to be tested.  Would the pharmaceutical grade make a difference in the ability to preserve the urine?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The grade for conservation is rather irrelevant. But is very relevant for the analysis, so it should be p.a. grade ( per analysis, try Sigma or Merck ) or similar. Farmaceutical grade could be good, but there should be run blank tests for pure water samples ( or  pure urine ). Or making parallel analysis for old and new fluoride batches.